# "There aren’t seven colors in the rainbow" is this claim appropriate?

Tags: optics

This [post](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-7-colours-in-the-rainbow-while-there-are-only-3-or-4-colours-that-appear-to-us) says

> `There aren’t seven colors in the rainbow`, or any other specific number; Newton described seven colors in large part because of the supposed “special” qualities associated with that number. In reality, the spectrum of visible light is continuous, and the number of distinguishable shades within the total range depends on the individual’s sensitivities. Color is simply a perception, after all; in a very real sense, it’s “all in your head.”

Actually, the colors could be defined by frequency and wavelength, for example, the [wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum#Spectral_colors) of red ranges 625–740 nm

So, "there aren’t seven colors in the rainbow", is this claim appropriate?

if yes, how could fit that to [Sir Isaac Newton's prism experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersive_prism), where, the dispersion of white light into colors by a prism led Sir Isaac Newton to conclude that white light consist of a mixture of different colors.

Comment: the boundary between colors is cultural too. In some cultures blue and green are the same color, same as orange and red. In any case our brain classifies a continuum into discrete categories. It happens in other perceptual categories too, such as sound.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the seven colours are an arbitrary classification. Our eyes are sensitive to three colour ranges, see [Color vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could fit that to Sir Isaac Newton's prism experiment, where, the dispersion of white light into colors by a prism led Sir Isaac Newton to conclude that white light consist of a mixture of different colors.